# Error 180008: Unable to queue Triggered Send Request. There are no Valid Subscribers in a Marketing Cloud API Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I have setup a triggered send AMPscripts in a cloud page, also created Tiggered Send under interaction, everything seems to be normal. But when I submit the form I am getting this error which I managed to pass through the parameters on to my error page.

> **Error 180008: Unable to queue Triggered Send Request.**
> There are no Valid Subscribers" in a Marketing Cloud API Triggered Send

**Here is the AMPscript setup:**

```
%%[
    [name="profileFormPost";type="POST"]

    SET @FirstName = RequestParameter("FirstName")
    SET @Surname = RequestParameter("Surname")
    SET @email = RequestParameter("email")

    SET @SubFirstName = RequestParameter("SubFirstName")
    SET @SubSurname = RequestParameter("SubSurname")
    SET @Subemail = RequestParameter("Subemail")

    SET @Travel_option = IIF(RequestParameter("Travel_option")=='true',1,0)
    SET @Additional_option = IIF(RequestParameter("Additional_option")=='true',1,0)
    SET @AdditionalFeed = RequestParameter("AdditionalFeed")

    SET @AddFirstName1 = RequestParameter("AddFirstName1")
    SET @AddSurname1 = RequestParameter("AddSurname1")

    SET @AddFirstName2 = RequestParameter("AddFirstName2")
    SET @AddSurname2 = RequestParameter("AddSurname2")

    SET @AddFirstName3 = RequestParameter("AddFirstName3")
    SET @AddSurname3 = RequestParameter("AddSurname3")

    SET @AddFirstName4 = RequestParameter("AddFirstName4")
    SET @AddSurname4 = RequestParameter("AddSurname4")

    SET @RSVP_Submit_Date = RequestParameter("RSVP_Submit_Date")

    /* Update DE */

    SET @status =
        InsertData
        (
            "RSVP_Test", 
            "FirstName", @FirstName,
            "Surname", @Surname,
            "email", @email,

            "SubFirstName", @SubFirstName,
            "SubSurname", @SubSurname,
            "Subemail", @Subemail,

            "Travel_option", @Travel_option,
            "Additional_option", @Additional_option,
            "AdditionalFeed", @AdditionalFeed,

            "AddFirstName1", @AddFirstName1,
            "AddSurname1", @AddSurname1,

            "AddFirstName2", @AddFirstName2,
            "AddSurname2", @AddSurname2,

            "AddFirstName3", @AddFirstName3,
            "AddSurname3", @AddSurname3,

            "AddFirstName4", @AddFirstName4,
            "AddSurname4", @AddSurname4,

            "RSVP_Submit_Date", @RSVP_Submit_Date
        )

    /* Triggered Send */
    var @emailaddrr, @ts, @tsDef, @ts_subkey, @ts_sub, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode

    SET @emailaddrr = "test@gmail.com"

    SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
    SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
    SET @ts_subkey = @emailaddrr

    SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "xxxxxx")
    SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

    SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @ts_subkey)

    SET @attr1 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr2 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr3 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr4 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr5 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr6 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr7 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr8 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr9 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr10 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr11 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr12 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr13 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr14 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr15 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr16 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr17 = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SET @attr18 = CreateObject("Attribute")

    SetObjectProperty(@attr1, "Name", "FirstName")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr2, "Name", "Surname")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr3, "Name", "email")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr4, "Name", "SubFirstName")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr5, "Name", "SubSurname")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr6, "Name", "Subemail")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr7, "Name", "Travel_option")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr8, "Name", "Additional_option")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr9, "Name", "AdditionalFeed")

    SetObjectProperty(@attr10, "Name", "AddFirstName1")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr11, "Name", "AddSurname1")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr12, "Name", "AddFirstName2")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr13, "Name", "AddSurname2")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr14, "Name", "AddFirstName3")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr15, "Name", "AddSurname3")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr16, "Name", "AddFirstName4")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr17, "Name", "AddSurname4")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr18, "Name", "RSVP_Submit_Date")

    SetObjectProperty(@attr1, "Value", @FirstName)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr2, "Value", @Surname)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr3, "Value", @email)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr4, "Value", @SubFirstName)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr5, "Value", @SubSurname)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr6, "Value", @Subemail)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr7, "Value", @Travel_option)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr8, "Value", @Additional_option)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr9, "Value", @AdditionalFeed)

    SetObjectProperty(@attr10, "Value", @AddFirstName1)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr11, "Value", @AddSurname1)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr12, "Value", @AddFirstName2)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr13, "Value", @AddSurname2)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr14, "Value", @AddFirstName3)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr15, "Value", @AddSurname3)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr16, "Value", @AddFirstName4)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr17, "Value", @AddSurname4)
    SetObjectProperty(@attr18, "Value", @RSVP_Submit_Date)

    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr1)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr2)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr3)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr4)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr5)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr6)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr7)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr8)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr9)

    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr10)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr11)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr12)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr13)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr14)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr15)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr16)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr17)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr18)

    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
    SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

    IF @status == 1 AND @ts_statusCode == "OK" THEN
            Redirect(CloudPagesURL(152))
    ELSE
            Redirect(CloudPagesURL(151, 'TMsg', @ts_statusMsg, 'TStatus', @ts_statusCode, 'Terror', @errorCode))
    ENDIF
]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you checked the option **Add subscribers to this list** under *Subscriber Management* when creating your triggered send.

To verify this option, go to *Email Studio > Interactions > Triggered Emails > Messages > Email > Triggered Sends* and navigate to your send definition and click on the name.

**Additional Info:** The only other reason I got this error was due to a bug in contact model which needed to be fixed by salesforce support, but shouldn't occur any more since one of the releases earlier this year.

Comment: I have checked the option and still throws me the same error.